# Rewriting migration and db:reset

Tags: ruby-on-rails, migration, reset

I created an integer for a phone number, and then learned that it is better to consider it as a string due to it's size.
I decided then to change directly the migration and apply db:reset instead of adding a new migration since the project is only on my computer at this moment. Db:reset worked but it doesn't seem that my database changed.

It raised a lot of questions :

Is there a command to analyse a database and identify the types of its columns ?

Does db:reset allow to modify a migration, like after rolling back a migration ?

Even though it isn't preferable, what are the conditions to modify directly a migration ?

Comment: To modify a migration `db:rollback` will work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `db:reset` task resets the database by dropping the database and then loading schema.rb - it does not run migrations again.  If you dropped the database, then created it and ran `db:migrate` then you should get the desired outcome

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. This really helped me to go forward and clean up some migrations.

Answer (score 1):

Change the field as **string** in migration, then run the commands:-

```
rake db:drop
rake db:create
rake db:migrate
```

And it will change the field type from integer to string.

Comment: Thanks a lot for expliciting the commands. This helped me too.